# How to save html output in Rmarkdown

Tags: html, r-markdown, kable

This is the first time I am using rmarkdown to knit a document into an html output. I see the output as an html document, no problem. However the output is linked to my personal working directory (example:file:///C:/Users/e337384/table_formatting.html).

````
    ---
title: "Inter-Rater Agreement (Long Beach)"
output:
  html_document: default
  word_document: default
date: "2/6/2020"
---

```{r,echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(knitr)
require(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
options(knitr.table.format = "html")
```
````

I would like to be able to share the html document with my team, but since the output is linked to my drive only I can see it. How do I save this output in a way that allows me to share this html output?!

Comment: By default when you knit the document the output will be saved in the same directory as the Rmd and you can then distribute that file as you like.

Comment: That html output opens up in a browser, that page is linked to my drive so no one else can see it..

Answer (score 0):

Recently, the export mechanism for files has changed slightly.
Now you have to check the corresponding check-box of the file you wish to export and then select More -> Export, as shown in this picture:
[image]

Comment: is it possible to save the output while the html rendering ends?